# Writing recursion function for probability

Tags: r, function, recursion

I am trying to find where the probability reaches a certain point; then, the function will return the value responsible for this probability.

The function I wrote takes two arguments
p represents the number of CPUs
q the number of jobs processed by each CPU

The function wants to optimise the number of CPUs in a server that will guarantee a 0.9 probability that each CPU will handle only one job simultaneously. Therefore, the number of processors (p) needs to be > the number of jobs (q).

```
opcpu <- function(p,q){
  if (p < q){
    paste("The number of processors should be",q," or more")
  } else {
    prob = prod(p:(p-(q-1)))/p^q
    while (prob < 0.9){
      p = p + 1
      opcpu(p,q)
    }
    return(p)
  }
}
```

I wrote the function as a recursion function. But it seems there is something wrong.

I tried to run the function, but it is not working. Solving the problem by trial and error gives that p = 631 when q = 12.

Comment: Why do you include opcpu(p,q) inside the code?

Comment: What is the motivation for using recursion here?

Comment: @chrisjude that’s what’s meant by a [recursive function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursion_(computer_science)) - a function that calls itself to iterate until a solution is found.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You’re on the right track. Try using `if` instead of `while`, and returning either `p` or a recursive call:

```
opcpu <- function(p,q) {
  if (p < q) {
    stop("The number of processors should be", q, " or more")
  }
  prob <- prod(p:(p-(q-1)))/p^q
  if (prob < 0.9) {
    opcpu(p+1,q)
  } else {
    p
  }
}

opcpu(12,12)
# 631
```

Or you could use `while` instead of recursion:

```
opcpu <- function(p,q) {
  if (p < q) {
    stop("The number of processors should be", q, " or more")
  }
  prob <- prod(p:(p-(q-1)))/p^q
  while (prob < 0.9){
    p <- p + 1
    prob <- prod(p:(p-(q-1)))/p^q
  }
  p
}

opcpu(12,12)
# 631
```

Note, I changed your `paste()` to `stop()`, since it seems you’re trying to indicate that `p < q` isn’t valid input. Another option would be to just start testing at `p = q` if the input is missing or less than `q`:

```
opcpu <- function(p,q) {
  if (missing(p) || p < q) p <- q
  prob <- prod(p:(p-(q-1)))/p^q
  if (prob < 0.9) {
    opcpu(p+1,q)
  } else {
    p
  }
}

opcpu(q = 12)
# 631
```